# Where does the Gantz anime branch off?

Tags: gantz

I really liked the Gantz anime. It was crazy, a mind trip, and overall an enjoyable (if somewhat graphic) show. But I've been told the manga is better, and goes in a wildly different direction. What episodes in Gantz are based off the manga plot, and where does the plot truly start to branch?

Note, I'm not looking for minor differences, though bonus points for noting those. I'm really looking for when the major branching in plot occurs.

Comment: Ive Heard its btter to reread the manga but if u really wanna go start reading from(Ch 8 volume 90 alone) thats just after the statue fight the allvs kuruno fight doesnt happen in the manga

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manga and the anime diverge during the anime's last battle. The last battle in the anime never occurred in the manga. Gonzo needed a way to end the series and created a weird introspective fight yourself battle. The manga went on with more battles and more characters, ongoing for a long time, and I guess Gonzo didn't want the series to just suddenly stop.

I don't remember all of the minor differences, there were some during the battles, especially the one during the statues, but those still followed the manga more or less faithfully.

Comment: Do you happen to know why Gonzo needed to kill the anime before the end of the manga?

Comment: @TheLQ I don't have any references to back this up but I'd guess it's the typical the "deal/contract was for X (26) number of episodes that span N (2) seasons so that's how many was planned". In some cases, the broadcaster or sponsors may want more episodes for a TV run, but Gantz wasn't a daytime network show so the 26 total episodes was probably all that was ever going to be made.